# How do I make groups for commands in discord.py and use them in different cogs?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working on a bot and I want the commands of the bot to be added to different groups but I don't know how to make group.

**Is there a way to make the group in the main bot file and then use it in cogs?**

Answer (score 2):

I think you know how to create them with this example.

```
@client.group(name='system', invoke_without_command=True)
async def system():
    pass


@system.command(name='load')
async def hello_subcommand():
    print('test')
```

The part of `invoke_without_command=True`will make sure the commands aren't double executed.

The command in this code would be {prefix}system hello

Comment: I want to make group in my main bot file and then add the commands in that group in my cog files. So is there a way to do that?